# 'Error 522' on Math.SE

Tags: support, math-se, cloudflare

Since yesterday, I have been facing a problem in accessing Math SE.

Whenever I try to do so, I get the following response:

> [image]

Is there suddenly a heavy increase in traffic on that site?

Comment: I don't experience this, so there must be something in the connections between the Mumbai CloudFlare site and SE's servers that's messed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/ there were issues in Mumbai earlier today:

[image: Cloudflare Mumbai issues]

and earlier

[image: Cloudflare moar Mumbai issues]

Those should be resolved now.